# How to Draw on Google Map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api-javascript-client

I need to create a shape on the google map. If the user wants to create a shape(Polygon, Circle, Rectangle, Square) with the help of Drawer he will be able to draw shapes.

Is there any related feature of Google Maps which I can use to achieve this feature?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is, you may try reading Drawing Manager from Google Maps Api [Drawing Layer (Library)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer)

Here is a working example of what you can achive

[GoogleEx_DrawingTools](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_DrawingTools_deleteAll.html)